# How to open a Popup Panel by clicking a cell in the CellTable?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2, gwt-2.2-celltable, popuppanel

I have a CellTable being displayed like shown below-[image]

On click of the Delete button I want to open a Popup panel in the center of the screen which should contain a Flow Panel and a Button within it.
Right now for the Delete button I have the following function-

```
deleteColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Contact, String>() {
        public void update(int index, Contact object, String value) {           
            try {
                int removeIndex = CONTACTS.indexOf(object);
                CONTACTS.remove(removeIndex);

                table.setRowCount(CONTACTS.size(), true);
                table.setRowData(CONTACTS);

                table.redraw();

            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }});
```

I do not understand how to update my function for the same. A sample code will surely help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just displaying a `PopupPanel`?

Something like this:

```
PopupPanel popup = new PopupPanel(true);
FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
//add Button etc
popup.setSize("1100px","500px");
popup.clear();
popup.add(panel);
popup.show();
popup.center();
```

If you want to display a confirm dialog than this code is easier:

```
if (Window.confirm("Do you really want to delete the dataset?"))
{
     //delete code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    ButtonCell buttonCell = new ButtonCell(){
        @Override
        public Set<String> getConsumedEvents() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //return super.getConsumedEvents();
            Set<String> events = new HashSet<String>();
            events.add("click");

            return events;
        }
    };
    productTable.addColumn(new Column<ProductDetails, String>(buttonCell) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(ProductDetails object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "Edit";
        }
        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element elem,
                ProductDetails object, NativeEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBrowserEvent(context, elem, object, event);
            if("click".equals(event.getType())){
                presenter.onEditButtonClicked(object);
            }
        }
    }, "Commands");
```

Please try it out and let me know the result. I just wrote and havent test it yet :|